# Find Independent Vectors (High Performance)

Tags: algorithm, performance, matrix, graphics, linear-algebra

I'm in desperate need of a high performance algorithm to reduce a matrix to its independent vectors (row echelon form), aka find the basis vectors. I've seen the Bareiss algorithm and Row Reduction but they are all too slow, if anyone could recommend a faster implementation I'd be grateful!!! Happy to use TBB parallelisation.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like all of the algorithms are running in `O(n^3)` time so you will need to be more specific when saying `faster implementation` since it can be achieved by code optimizations. (When saying `Row Reduction` you mean [`Gaussian elimination`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)?)

Comment: Yes exactly, I'm hoping there is a linear algebra method to circumvent a lot of the processing or allow parallelisation. By faster implementation I should have said number of operations.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with the reduced echelon form? Do you just need the basis vectors to have them or are you trying to solve a system of equation? If you're solving a system of equations you can do an LU factorization and probably get faster calculation times. Otherwise gaussian elimination with partial pivoting is your fastest option.

Also do you know if your matrix is of a special form? Like upper or lower triangular for example. If it is then you can rewrite some of these algorithms to be faster based on the type of matrix that you have.